# How Apex Clone Works

Tags: apex, object, omnichannel, clone

I tried cloning a PendingServiceRouting object within the apex class. But few attributes are missing in the cloned object(Id, CreatedDate). Can someone explain what is happening here? How can we copy the whole object the correct way?

```
original object - [Id=00ABCD, RoutingPriority=3, CreatedDate=2022-09-26 14:31:02, WorkItemId=22ABC, ...]

after cloning   - [RoutingPriority=3, WorkItemId=22ABC, ...]
```

Comment: Are you expecting to clone Id and CreatedDate? Can you edit the post and clarify which fields were not getting cloned?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

When using the clone method, you need to pass in four `true` values to preserve/copy everything.

```
sObject clonedRecord = sourceRecord.clone(true, true, true, true);
```

You can read more in the [documentation](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexref.meta/apexref/apex_methods_system_sobject.htm).

The four parameters are:

- preserveId: true to keep the Id field, false to set to null
- isDeepClone: true to copy parent/child records, false keeps the original memory references (e.g. modifying one modifies the other)
- preserveReadonlyTimeStamps: true to keep CreatedDate, LastModifiedDate, SystemModStamp, false to null these fields
- preserveAutoNumber: true to keep auto-number fields, false to null these fields

Comment: Also just to mention, default values are all `false` which means that `clone()` is the same as `clone(false, false, false, false)`.